# CSS width of input element's contents. min-content doesn't work for inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

`min-content` and `max-content` don't seem to care about the input element's value:

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

CSS totally ignores the input's value when figuring out min-content, just using some default width that never changes no matter the contents:

[image]

How can I make the CSS take the "content" (value) width into account:

[image]

Without using javascript to set `width`, `min-width` or `max-width`

Comment: @tacoshy no because the answers very clearly set `width`, `min-width`, `max-width`

Comment: there are no other answer you can get. CSS has no way in setting the width to fit the content. The only way to do it is through scripting but you obviosly can't set a width of an element if you not allowed to use width.

Comment: Consider using a [`contenteditable`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) element instead.

Comment: @tacoshy the top answer on the duplicate has a solution to this question: set `size` using JS and `width: auto;`

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible without JavaScript.

You have to programmatically set the input's width to the length of its value. This can be simplified with the `ch` unit.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.style.width = this.value.length + 'ch'
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: JavaScript is allowed just not `width`, `min-width`, `max-width`, on the input

Comment: @minseong Without using one of those properties it makes it impossible to do it with JS or CSS.

Comment: So it is possible with CSS using those properties?

Comment: @minseong No, if you can't use those properties, you can't set the input's width at all.

Comment: Only JS is not allowed to set those properties. And if it's impossible, then a proof that it is impossible would be the selected answer.

Comment: how do you want to proof it that it is impossible? It can only be proofed emperic which would blow the frame of the SO guidelines.

Comment: It is not even impossible. Setting `size` attribute and using css `width: auto;` makes this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code in the script tag or in the `useEffect()` block in React. It will take care for all the input.

`Note:`
If you want to do it for the specific input tag within a certain div, you might want to use a different CSS selector.

```js
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputElements.forEach((input) => {
  input.style.width = input.value.length + 'ch';
});
```